# MySQL - replace space in whole table in all rows and columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, replace

Ok, maybe this is really simple, but I can´t figure it out by myself:

First I have a csv file.
I´m importing this with
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`
... into a mysql table with 20 columns and over 10000 rows.

Then there are fields with content = " " in some rows and columns that I wanted to replace with an "". 
I don´t know, in what columns a " " will be, so I want to iterate through the whole table.

So I thought on something like this:
`REPLACE INTO products (XXX) VALUE ("") WHERE XXX = " "`
... where XXX are all column-names.

Can somebody give me hint for this?
Maybe I should do it within php?
Thanks.

[Edit] Or maybe there is a way to do it while importing the csv-file itself?

[Edit] I just thought on doing a `UPDATE table SET column = "" WHERE column=" "`. But I want this without writing 20 querys for every single column.

Comment: you do `update products set col = "" where col = " "` to update columns

Comment: Use INFORMATION_SCHEMA to generate the statements you need.

Comment: @czifro: same time same thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn´t get the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to work so I tried this:

```
$rs = $db->query('SELECT * FROM mytablename LIMIT 0');

for ($i = 0; $i < $rs->columnCount(); $i++) {
    $col = $rs->getColumnMeta($i);
    $columns[] = $col['name'];
    $rs2 = $db->query('UPDATE mytablename SET '.$col['name'].'="" WHERE '.$col['name'].'=" "');
}
```

It worked out well.

Answer (score 1):

As Mihai mentioned you can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables to generate the SQL To execute.

Use the following script to generate the SQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE ', TABLE_NAME ,' SET ',COLUMN_NAME ,'=\"\" WHERE ', COLUMN_NAME  ,'=\" \";') AS  SQLCOMMAND
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE data_type IN ('VARCHAR' ,'CHAR')
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='your_database_name'
```

This will print out a update statement for all columns that is `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` and update those column values to "".

Comment: I did a `mysql_query($sql)` and it said, it was successfull. But did´t change anything. What was wrong? My $sql was: `$sql = "SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE mytablename SET ',COLUMN_NAME ,'=\"\" WHERE ', COLUMN_NAME  ,'=\" \";') AS  SQLCOMMAND
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE data_type IN ('VARCHAR' ,'CHAR')
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='mydbname'";`